# How to make an Image to resize itself

Tags: html

Hi here my problem and sorry in advance for the bad english it is not my native langagues.I'm doing a VB.net application and right now I'm doing a banner that goes on top. What i want is that she can resize automaticly for example if the customer minimize a bit the windows or narrow it. I want the image to goes smaller. Right now I've played with the width but it didn't seems to have done anything. It work for table but not for images.

Here the code for the Images:

```
.style2 {
    width:auto;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us an example?

Comment: check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762610/how-to-make-header-image-responsive

BTW your English is not bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have accomplished it before using something like this:

```
.style2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 400px;
}
```

(Change the value of 'max-height' to fit your image.)

This may have to be altered depending on your layout, and you may need to set certain restrictions on parent elements, but this works for me.