# Wordpress header not resizing with different devices

Tags: html, css, wordpress, responsive-design

First if all I apologize if I have posted this in the wrong place.

I am working on a website for a customer and am getting to the stage where it is almost ready to be released apart from a few minor tweaks.

I am using wordpress to develop the website - I have never used wordpress before so I am kind of learning as I am going along and I am glad the customer understands that.

The problem I am having is related to the header image. I have uploaded a header image by going into `Appearance->Header` and picked an image that is stored on my hard disk.

The header looks really good on my PC however when I open the website on my phone the header image doesn't get scaled down and the writing on the banner (located on the left) just disappears so all you see is half of the header banner which doesn't look very good.

I am using `Mantra` as the theme and the responsiveness works fine on my phone but the header image is never re-sized.

I have spend some time on here trying other people's suggestions and the most common solution is found here: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762610/how-to-make-header-image-responsive) however I am not sure to which CSS file to add the code.

I would appreciate if somebody out there could point me in the right direction so that I can overcome this issue.

Comment: show us some of the code around the header image and the CSS

Comment: @Andrew thanks for the reply. I uploaded the image using Wordpress rather than writing my own HTML and CSS so I am not sure which bit you would like to see. I am quite confident with HTML/CSS however I am not sure what to show you. As I said I am learning as I am going along and so far it has been a rather bumpy road

Comment: show me the link then to the page

Comment: @Andrew the site is currently down for maintenance - I am using a  plugin that blocks public access to the page. However I have used Developer tools of my browser and this is the CSS it associates with the header image: `#branding {
background: url("http://www.mysite.co.uk/sites/design2/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/FINAL_BANNER2.png") no-repeat;
width: 1100px;
height: 200px;
}`

Comment: @jhunlio thanks for your reply. I am not sure how posting the image will help solve the problem? It's a coding problem (confused)

Comment: @Andrew I seem to have managed to solve the problem partially - the image now gets resized however there is a big grey gap under the image - in other words it resizes itself horizontally but leaves a gap vertically. How can I get around this? I believe I have to edit the CSS file of the header DIV rather than header image, am I correct? also, thanks for your help

Comment: Try having the `height` of the image: `height:100%;` It may make it look a little stretched. Or you could make the image height taller and if its a background image the it will cut off what you need

Comment: @Andrew could you add your comment as an answer so I can select it as the correct answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try having the `height` of the image: `height:100%;` It may make it look a little stretched. Or you could make the image height taller and if its a background image the it will cut off what you need

Answer (score 0):

Responsive use in header .. try this in your CSS

```
.header {
background-size: 50%, auto
}
```

change 50% with yours

edit :

use image as background-image

Comment: thanks for the reply. could you explain which file i add the following code to? I am not even sure where the CSS for the header image is located. Sorry for the stupid question